# How to cover expand to another controls wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

I have a code snippet like below. I want to click the test button to show the expander, and let the expander cover the TextBlock and ComboBox in the same row. I have tried somebody's solution to set ZIndex, but doesn't work. Anyone can help?

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="show" TargetProperty="Height">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestRec"  Duration="0:0:0.3" From="0" To="300"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="showRectangle" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test TextBlock" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="B"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="C"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="D"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="TestRec" Height="0">
        <Expander Header="abc" IsExpanded="True">
            <Expander.Content>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</Grid>


 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginStoryboard(FindResource("show") as Storyboard);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button?

Comment: @OscarPaz the expander content and combobox content mixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background of the expander to White.

```
<Expander Header="abc" IsExpanded="True" Background="White">
```

Comment: As far as I know, it's the same thing.

Comment: You are right. I didn't check that first. I changed the answer.

Comment: If I explicitly set background, it will not work in high contrast mode

Comment: To my knowledge the only option left is to hide the other two items in the same way you show the expander.

Answer (score 0):

That the solution to be reliable, I suggest you hide them in the `Storyboard`. Set for the controls names, in this case used `TestTextBlock` and `TestComboBox`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

...

<Storyboard x:Key="show">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestRec" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                     Duration="0:0:0.3" 
                     From="0" 
                     To="300" />

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TestTextBlock"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">

        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <sys:Double>0.0</sys:Double>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TestComboBox"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">

        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <sys:Double>0.0</sys:Double>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

In this case it is also possible use `DoubleAnimation` if you will use the `Opacity` property. And according to another `Storyboard` you will show them by setting `Opacity` to 1.0.

Comment: Why using ZIndex couldn't work? Is there any other way except to set other control's opacity? the expander has a explicit height, but the other control's may very long, maybe I should't use a textblock and a combobox here. If it's a ListView, I want the expander covers part of the listview, if setting listview's opacity, the whole listview will not display

Comment: @James: In my case `ZIndex` works fine for ComboBox and Expander. Not only works for `TextBlock`, probably because he's in another column.

Comment: @James: If you want, I can show you my example with `ZIndex`. But I think you need to make your example: with either `ZIndex` when you hide a control within the same column, or when you hide the other controls by the set `Opacity` or `Visibility`.

Comment: thanks! I only want to create a floating layer over the normal view. When I click the button, a floating layer view display, click again, it disappears. The other controls in the view are not change during the period.

Comment: @James: But in this situation, installing `Zindex` not help much. It will only show one Control on top of another, while the other will be visible. That is, in this situation, it can be shown `ComboBox` over the `Expander` or vice versa. You will suit it?

Comment: this is what I don't want, I want the expand can cover over controls.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @Bizz, you can set a style for your Expander, if pc is not in highcontrast mode,
set Background to white.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```